# Open the shared excel file, without displaying it , with Excel 2016 and win 10

Tags: excel, vba

With the following VBA code, I open an excel file to modify it and I would like to keep it hidden.
If the file Pippo. xls is shared, it will still be visible immediately after opening, if instead the file pippo is not shared then it remains hidden.
The problem described occurs with Windows 10 and Office 2016, with Office 2010 and Win 7 everything worked correctly.
Please help me, I can not find a solution.

```
Sub TEST()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\PIPPO.xlsx")
'xlApp.Visible = False

Stop

' more code for edit the file pippo

xlBook.Close SAVECHANGES:=False

Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Normally opening an excel file with vba this remains hidden instead if the file is shared becomes visible. This is my problem with Office 2016, can anyone try ?

```
`
```

Comment: What do you mean by shared?

Comment: shared in a corporate network for multiple user access.

Comment: From the excel toolbar:
review / share workbook.
from the form put the flag on the item "allow changes from multiple users at the same time ...." and save the settings with the OK button.